# JBoss AS 7.1 - datasource how to encrypt password

Tags: java, security, jboss, password-protection, jboss7.x

In JBoss AS 5, I have a datasource defined in *-ds.xml but put username/encrypted password in *-jboss-beans.xml.

Now in JBoss AS 7.1, the datasource is defined in standalone.xml or domain.xml.
Where do I put the encrypted password in AS 7.1?

In other words, how is a clear password encrypted and secured in AS 7?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In AS7 you can use the SecureIdentityLoginModule to add an encrypted password domain. For instance, you can define a security domain in standalone.xml or domain.xml:

```
<security-domain name="EncryptedPassword">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="SecureIdentity" flag="required">
      <module-option name="username" value="test"/>
      <module-option name="password" value="encrypted_password"/>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Then you can add this security domain in your particular data source that uses this userid/pwd combination in standalone.xml or domain.xml:

```
  <datasource ... >
       .....
       <security>
              <security-domain>EncryptedPassword</security-domain>
       </security>
  </datasource>
```

To encrypt the password itself, you can run this command (please verify the versions of picketbox jar and logging jar in your particular AS7 download to substitute accordingly):

```
java -cp $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.0.6.<beta|final>.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.1.0.<some_version>.jar:$CLASSPATH org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule password
```

This will return an encrypted password back that you can use in your security domain.

You can read more about JBoss AS7 security subsystem [here](http://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Security+subsystem+configuration). Since *open source rocks*, you can see how the encoding code works in the source code of [SecureIdentityLogin](http://source.jboss.org/browse/PicketBox/trunk/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/picketbox/datasource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java?r=276). You will notice in the source code that it uses `Blowfish` for encryption.

Comment: Also see the answer from shatk, the managedConnectionFactoreName module-option needs to be provided.

Comment: Blog [post](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1026) describing these steps and complete datasource file

Answer (score 6):

Below is the complete security Domain Configuration for Jboss AS-7 :

```
     <security-domains>
        <!--  Security Setting's --> 
        <security-domain name="encryptedSecurity" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
                <module-option name="username" value="user_name"/>
                <module-option name="password" value="encrypted_password"/>
                <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=dataSource-1-PoolName,dataSource-2-PoolName"/>
            </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
```

Comment: Is actually possible to have the same security module for multiple datasources? I've been reading jboss documentation and they only mention one datasource:  jboss.jca:service={type},name={jndiName}. I see you have specified name=dataSource-1-PoolName,dataSource-2-PoolName

Answer (score 4):

For who is interested on having this running on windows (and in my case on JBoss EAP 6.4...)

```
set JBOSS_HOME=C:\dev\jboss\jboss-eap-6.4
set MYPATH=%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.
jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logging\main\jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA-redhat-2.jar;
java -classpath %MYPATH% org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule SecretPass

Encoded password: 13e0362237c93a9cda89f5b3da271521
```

Hope this helps,
Matteo

Answer (score 2):

In an environment CentOS release 6.3, JBoss-EAP-6.0.0 this only worked with code="SecureIdentity", 
using picketbox-4.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar for password encryption.

```
<security-domain name="some-ds-EncryptedPassword">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="SecureIdentity" flag="required">
      <module-option name="username" value="username"/>
      <module-option name="password" value="encrypted_password"/>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

code="SecureIdentityLogin" gives "PB00024: Access Denied:Unauthenticated caller:null".

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Security+subsystem+configuration

Answer (score 2):

create simple project with jars(
jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA-redhat-2.jar
picketbox-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar
picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final-redhat-3.jar
picketbox-infinispan-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar) and run custom class with input args:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule()
                .main(args);

    }

}
```

Output will be: Encoded password: 3d5bc094c128...