# How to encrypt keytool keypass and storepass

Tags: security, encryption, jboss, certificate, keytool

I am using the following link for 2-way ssl in JBoss. It works fine for me.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/complete-tutorial-for-configuring-ssl-https-on-wildfly

I am using the following command to generate key pair, using key password(keypass) as secret.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias client -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore client.keystore -dname "CN=client" -keypass secret -storepass secret
```

Like wise, I follow the steps in above link and I am able to enable https.

While doing so, one of the entry that is created in standalone-full.xml is as follows:

```
<tls>
    <key-stores>
        <key-store name="demoKeyStore">
        <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
        <implementation type="JKS"/>
        <file path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </key-store>
    </key-stores>
    <key-managers>
        <key-manager name="demoKeyManager" key-store="demoKeyStore">
        <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
        </key-manager>
    </key-managers>
    <server-ssl-contexts>
        <server-ssl-context name="demoSSLContext" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="demoKeyManager"/>
    </server-ssl-contexts>
</tls>
```

Here the clear-text value is **secret**, which was used while doing key generation. Since it is visible to anyone having access to standalone-full.xml file, I want to protect it.

**Question**: How do I encrypt the clear-text attribute with value "secret" in the xml file.

Few possible way I could think of is storing it in vault (I have not tried it yet) or encrypt the password using some other techniques

https://docs.rapidminer.com/9.0/server/administration/security/securing-passwords-in-jboss.html

[JBoss AS 7.1 - datasource how to encrypt password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520997/jboss-as-7-1-datasource-how-to-encrypt-password)

What is the best way to solve above problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation and researching, I have narrowed down to using **credential store**. Please refer to following link [Credential Store V/s Password Vault](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/how_to_configure_server_security/securely_storing_credentials#:%7E:text=Credential%20Store%20%2D%20Introduced%20in%20JBoss,them%20in%20a%20storage%20file.&text=Password%20Vault%20%2D%20Primarily%20used%20in,outside%20of%20the%20configuration%20files.)

**Password Vault** is Primarily used in legacy configurations, whereas  **Credential Store** introduced with the elytron subsystem, credential stores allow for secure storage and usage of credentials.

**Execute the following commands in CLI**

**Create a Credential Store**

`/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=my_store:add(location="cred_stores/my_store.jceks", relative-to=jboss.server.data.dir,  credential-reference={clear-text=supersecretstorepassword},create=true)`

**Add a Credential to the Credential Store**

`/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=my_store:add-alias(alias=database-pw, secret-value="speci@l_db_pa$$_01")`

**List the Credentials in the Credential Store**

`/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=STORE_NAME:read-aliases()`

Once the above steps are executed using CLI, need to make changes in `<credential-reference/>` tag.

You can also fine working example here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/using-credential-stores-to-store-your-passwords-in-wildfly-11

Above is an example for datasource, but it works similarly for encrypting `clear-text` for certificates.